# Sync MacBook and iMac

Tags: data-synchronization

I have both a MacBook and an iMac.

Is there any way I can have them both sync with files, apps, everything, like if one was a copy of another?

Comment: Do you want this synchronization to happen on an ongoing basis, or when you run a synchronization command? Obviously you'll be limited to the smaller of the sizes of the drives on the two machines.

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

1. CarbonCopyCloner which puts a nice interface on rsync.
2. Use the built in [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) command-line utility. It's what it is designed for. You might want to only sync the Application Folder and some parts of your User folder. You may encounter license problems if an application that uses the SMBIOS MachineID has a mismatch.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into setting up a [Netboot server](http://lowendmac.com/hodges/07/0118.html).